# What is going on in this make file line?

Tags: makefile

Ok so im getting in to Kernel Module Development and the guides all pretty much use the same basic make file that contains this line:

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is a make file calling make? that seems recursive
2. what is the M for? i cant find a make -M flag in any of the man pages

Comment: There is no `-M` in your quoted make file text, either.

Comment: So what is the M if not a flag?

Comment: [Recursive make considered harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) notwithstanding, why do you consider it strange that `make` would recursively call `make`? `M` is just a variable being overridden at the command line.

Comment: Why not just include the recursive calls as logic in the initial make file? I guess its just a philosophical "why use recursion if something simpler exists"

Comment: Why not put your entire program in one C source file, and not bother with a makefile at all? Having multiple makefiles is a form of organization for your project. If you have many components to your project, and each of which is capable of being built separately, then having separate makefiles for each component can make a lot of sense.

Comment: Why a whole separate make file for a component  instead of a rule for each component? wouldn't separate make files confuse the default behavior of make? This strikes me as a personal preference at this point, although I do see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive use of `make` is a common technique for introducing modularity into your build process. For example, in your particular case, you could support a new architecture by putting the relevant component in a folder whose name matches the `uname -r` output for that architecture, and you wouldn't have to change the master makefile at all. Another example, if you make one component modular, it makes it much easier to reuse in another project without making large changes to the new project's master makefile.

Just like it can be helpful to separate your code into files, modules, and classes (the latter for languages other than C, obviously), it can be helpful to separate your build process into separate modules. It's just a form of organization to make managing your projects easier. You might group related functionality into separate libraries, or plugins, and build them separately. Different individuals or teams could work on the separate components without all of them needing write access to the master makefile. You might want to build your components separately so that you can test them separately.

It's not impossible to do all of these things without recursive use of `make`, of course, but it's one common way of organizing things. Even if you don't use `make` recursively, you're still going to end up with a bunch of different component "makefiles" on a large project - they'll just be imported or included into the master makefile, rather than standing alone by themselves and being run via separate invocations of `make`.

Creating and maintaining a single makefile for a very large project is not a trivial matter. However, as the article [Recursive make considered harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) describes, recursive use of `make` is not without its own problems, either.

As for your `M`, that's just overriding a variable at the command line. Somewhere in the makefile(s) the variable `M` will be used, and if you specify its value at the command line in this way, then the value you specify will override any other assignments to that variable that may occur in the makefile(s).